# How to identify the exact process_id that is causing slowness

Tags: unix, sybase

I have a database(Sybase) application that is running slow for all the users currently. I need to identify the exact process_id that is causing the slowness.

Running health checks(top, df) on the server will give me the data for all the processes. Is there a way to figure out the exact process that is causing slowness.

Comment: Firstly you need to confirm which Sybase database product you're using as there are a number available (Anywhere, Adaptive Server Enterprise, IQ). Usually you'll need to log into the database and run queries to identify the problem process/query though you cant get it from the Unix command line.

Comment: I am using a ASE 15.3. What kind of queries needs to be run to identify the process causing slowness ? Is there anyway we get the session Id of all processes.